# Why merged revisions are not shown in grayed out using tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

After merge revisions in trunk using Tortoise SVN, merged revision are not showing in grayed out. Can any one help me? Also, merged revisions are not showing in " Right-Clicking your Branch Folder > TortoiseSVN > Properties".

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem on my development PC. My colleague could well see the Already Merged icon, while I could not for some projects, but still could well for some others.
When I added a new merge, merge info was also missing when shown for my colleague. We could see that the file *wc.db* in the *.svn* folder for the project was smaller with me than with my colleague.
This is equivalent to my file not containing any merge info. I have tried to copy my colleague's *wc.db* into my *.svn* directory. So far, it seems to have solved the problem.
New merges that I perform now also are shown with merge info on my colleague's pc.